# Do I have to delete textures in GLSurfaceView?

Tags: android, memory, textures

After creating textures in Android OpenGL ES, do I have to explicitly delete these textures later using glDeleteTextures()?  If so, how would I set up a callback to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are automatically deleted once you move away from your app. The greater pitfall actually is to disregard the texture IDs if your app becomes active again - keep that in mind when your `onSurfaceChanged` is called again.

Answer (score 5):

If you are no longer using a texture, then you should call glDeleteTextures() so that the underlying hardware resources can be freed up.

But as EboMike said, you have to be careful about using a texture that was created from a previous context instance; to expand on that answer, I like to create a texture-wrangling class which wraps the texture's ID and which calls glDeleteTextures() from its finalize() method, but then also have an app-static int named "contextId" which gets incremented every time the GL context is created (i.e. in onSurfaceCreated); the texture wrangler should track the value of contextId when it's instantiated, and if the value changes on it, that means it should reload its textures (keeping in mind that the old texture IDs were already discarded along with the old context).